# How to display a collection of objects in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm implementing my first many-to-many relationship and I'm having some trouble getting the related collection to populate in my view

For example: simple blog w/ posts and tags

my post controller new action has this var

> @tags = Tag.all

next inside my view I have the following loop

```
<% for tag in @tags %>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<%=tag.id%>" value="<%=tag.id %>"><%=tag.description%>
<% end %>
```

In the MySQL database I have 2 tags listed but for some reason in the view they don't show (not even a single checkbox input so I assume my loop syntax is invalid)

Anything else I missed here?

Comment: The loop seems to be valid. Try output some text without tags in your loop.

Comment: throw a <%= debug tag%> inside the iterator.  I also suggest using @tags.each do |tag| as its more conventional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a problem with the new Active Record in Rails 3. Try:

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
```

It may look like it's just another method of looping over elements, but I've already had a few issues with Ruby acting on the ActiveQuery object instead of the desired query results.

Comment: This appears to work but it turns out the initial for loop actually worked after a clean db:create/db:migrate so I'm sure this was my fault - thanks for the help!